# How to set the size of LineRenderer from script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello :) My code below works fine. It can create a line renderer if you add gameobjects manually. What I want to know though is how to set the size dynamically of my points. Here's a sample [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgZi3.jpg) of what I'm talking about. On the bottom of the inspector, I can set the size of my points, sure. What I'm trying to do is how to code the size as, example 10 and not through the inspector.

How can I set the size of the points of the line renderer?

Here is my code:

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour {
    LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    public Transform[] points;
    private Vector3[] vP;
    int seg;



// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    lineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    Lines();
}

public void Lines() {
    seg = points.Length;
    vP = new Vector3[points.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
    {
        vP[i] = points[i].position;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < seg; i++)
    {
        float t = i / (float)seg;
        lineRenderer.numPositions = vP.Length;
        lineRenderer.SetPositions(vP);
    }

}

}
```

Comment: You do it the exact same way you dynamicly sized `vP`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain sir did you looked at the pic I attached? I wasn't able to dynamically do it. I had to manually set the size of points which is the array

Answer (score 1):

The [`LineRenderer.startWidth`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer-startWidth.html) and [`LineRenderer.endWidth`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer-endWidth.html) variabls are used to set the size of the `LineRenderer`.

The `0.2f` value seems to be fine for this.

```
public void Lines()
{
    lineRenderer.startWidth = 0.2f;
    lineRenderer.endWidth = 0.2f;

    seg = points.Length;
    vP = new Vector3[points.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
    {
        vP[i] = points[i].position;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < seg; i++)
    {
        float t = i / (float)seg;
        lineRenderer.numPositions = vP.Length;
        lineRenderer.SetPositions(vP);
    }
}
```

You can also use the [`LineRenderer.widthMultiplier`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer-widthMultiplier.html) variable but that's not necessary.

**EDIT:**

You just want to set the size of the `points` variable from code instead of Editor. Just do this:

```
int size = 10;
points = new Transform[size];
```

then loop over the points variable and fill the point's transform

```
for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
{
    points[i] = theGameObjectTransformToUse.transform;
}
```

If you don't have a `Transform` to fill it, you can create dummy GameObjects and use their transforms them to fill it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
{
    GameObject tempObj = new GameObject("dummy" + i);
    tempObj.transform.position = yourNewPostion;
    points[i] = tempObj.transform;
}
```

*Note*:

`lineRenderer.numPositions = vP.Length;` should be outside and before the for loop. It is unnecessary to do that in the for loop. You only need to set that once.

Comment: did you looked at the pic? I wasn't referring to the width of the line renderer sir but the size of the points which is the array. @Programmer I mean how to dynamically set the size of the array coz I tried changing the size of the array and set it to 10, but I couldn't. Not the width

Comment: That image does not explain your problem other than showing that the thickness is big. Check my Edited answer...

Comment: it's not the thickness that is big. The right bottom of the image which I had drawn with the red marker is what I was talking about. With my above code, it will only display the size of the points as 0 which I have to manually set the size as 10.  I was looking for a solution of instead of doing it manually, I can set it to 10 instead of 0. I tried your code but the size still won't change. @Programmer

Comment: Can't you the my updated answer? Read from where it says **EDIT:** down. `points = new Transform[size];`....